# Glassfish, JRuby, Rails 3 throws rake error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans, glassfish, rake, jruby

Hello 
I am currently using:

- Ubuntu 10.04LTS
- Netbeans 6.9.1 (with embedded JRuby 1.5.1)
- JDK6u17
- GlassFish Gem 1.0.2

I am using a old JDK because of this bug:
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-4785

I have partially completed application, but i want migrate to rails 3(currently application is in rails 2.3.8).

So i go to:
`$HOME/netbeans-6.9.1/ruby/jruby-1.5.1/bin` and type: `jruby gem install rails -v=3.0.3`. Everything is OK.

Then i create a sample RoR project and use some simple scaffold. Works.

But when i choose in Netbeans `rake db:migrate` it shows me message: `"db:migrate" taks does not exist`.

**Any idea how to fix that?**

I would be grateful for the help.

**UPDATE**

I have tested this in Ubuntu and it works fine.
But in Mac OS X this trick don't work.
So I made a symbolic link called `jrake` to `jruby/bin/rake`

```
cd /bin
ln -s /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans\ 6.9.1.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ruby/jruby-1.5.1/bin/rake jrake
```

and I just type `jrake db:migrate` in project Directory and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this link help?:

http://www.blakes-site.co.uk/blog/13/Fix-NetBeans-dbmigrate-task-does-not-exists-error/

**UPDATE**

Link broken - From the Google Cache of Blake Simpson's blog:

> I have recently reinstalled Ruby on Rails 3.0.0 and created a new
>   Rails project in NetBeans 9.6.1
>
> I could not migrate my database, or any other rake tasks for that
>   matter. I kept getting the error:
>
> ```
>  "db:migrate" task does not exist
> ```
>
> The solution is to right click your project select **"Run/Debug Rake
>   Task"** and then click the button titled **"Refresh Tasks"**.
>
> Once this is done you should see a list of all your rake tasks. After
>   this you can simply re-run the db:migrate task and it will work.